# Make a for-loop that makes "n" lists (i.e. 5 lists when n= 5 or 10 lists when n=10)

Tags: python, for-loop

I attempted several times to do this but failed

Attempt 1

```
num = int(input("How many products are you looking at: "))

for i in range(num):
    a="list"+str(i)
    a=[]
```

Attempt 2 (assume less than 26 lists)

```
num = int(input("How many products are you looking at: "))

alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

while(num>0):
    alphabet[0]=[]
    num=num-1
    alphabet=alphabet[1:]
```

Thanks for any and all help

EXTRA PART:

Thank you, thank you for all the help. I have one final step where I need to make n matrices. Is there a way to make an arbitrary number of matrices, say 5, where matrices titled something like matrix1=...... , matrix2=....., and so on? Then have the matrices in a list. I've been playing around with numpy in Python, and know how to make a matrix. Below is 3x3 matrix.

```
matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(3,3))
```

But a list of matrices is giving me issues. Here is my attempt.

```
listOfMatrices=list(map(lambda x:matrix,range(int(num))))
```

Another attempt.

```
[matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(n,n)) for _ in range(int(n)))]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good use case for a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
[[] for _ in range(int(input("How Many?")))]
```

This produces `[]` - an empty list on each iteration, but you can use any expression to build up a list of results as you wish.

The result is a list of items - in this case empty lists: `[[], [], ...]`.

You can, of course, utilise the value from your iterable, e.g:

```
>>> [["First Element of List {0}".format(i)] for i in range(int(input("How Many?")))]
How Many?5
[['First Element of List 0'], ['First Element of List 1'], 
 ['First Element of List 2'], ['First Element of List 3'], 
 ['First Element of List 4']]
```

Each of these lists is just like any other object. If you assign this list to a value (`items = [... for ... in ...]`) then you can access the sub-lists like any other item (`items[0]`) and from there, the items of the sub-lists (`items[0][0]`).

```
>>> items = [["First Element of List {0}".format(i)] for i in range(int(input("How Many?")))]
How Many?5
>>> items[1].append("Second Element of List 1")
>>> items
[
    ['First Element of List 0'], 
    ['First Element of List 1', 'Second Element of List 1'], 
    ['First Element of List 2'], 
    ['First Element of List 3'], 
    ['First Element of List 4']
]
```

Comment: bah I was trying to get him to get there through critical thinking +1 all the same :P

Comment: Thanks a ton. I wish I could "+1" this but I dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda x:list(),range(int(input("How Many?")))))
```

is one way

```
[[]]*int(input("How Many?"))
```

is another way (although it might behave different than you would think)

there are a whole lot of ways to do this, the best way is the one you write yourself by understanding

python has these things called list comprehensions

```
[do_something(item) for item in a_list]
```

would create a new list of do_something items

now  pretend you have already gotten the user input and have an integer

```
user_input = 5
#you might think the following would work
[do_something(i) for i in user_input] #this will give you an error since ints are not iterable
```

python will let you create a list out of a number pretty easily

```
 a_list_from_a_number = range( user_input )
```

now just use all those parts in order to write your own program :)

Comment: Using your code how can I call the first or second list in the command line?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean? ... that sentence doesn't make sense... you mean store it in a variable ?

Comment: Lets say I run "list(map(lambda x:list(),range(int(input("How Many?")))))". I get "[[], [], [], []]". How can I append the second list?

Comment: Never mind! I got it. For an example: "a[2].append(8)". Gives "[[], [], [8], []]"